# Unable to run Jupyter notebook, but running qtconsole

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am having 64 bit Anaconda Navigator installed on Windows 7. Am unable to run Jupyter notebook, but am able to run qtconsole.

The error given on launching notebook is

```
 [I 14:50:50.679 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying 
 another port.
 [I 14:50:50.680 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying 
 another port.
 [I 14:50:52.093 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded 
 from E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
 [I 14:50:52.093 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is 
 E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
 [W 14:50:52.249 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 321, in __init__
 self._run(['node', 'node-version-check.js'], cwd=HERE, quiet=True)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1165, in _run
 proc = Process(cmd, **kwargs)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", 
 line 73, in __init__
 self.proc = self._create_process(cwd=cwd, env=env)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", 
 line 131, in _create_process
 cmd[0] = which(cmd[0], kwargs.get('env'))
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\jlpmapp.py", 
 line 59, in which
 raise ValueError(msg)
 ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing 
 installation. 
 nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", 
 line 1454, in init_server_extensions
 func(self)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extension.py", 
 line 111, in load_jupyter_server_extension
 info = get_app_info(app_dir)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", 
 line 244, in get_app_info
 handler = _AppHandler(app_dir, logger)
 File "E:\Users\jiten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", 
 line 324, in __init__
 raise ValueError(msg)
 ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing 
 installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the 
 nodejs website.
 [I 14:50:55.229 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: 
 C:\Users\jiten
 [I 14:50:55.230 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
 [I 14:50:55.230 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
 [I 14:50:55.230 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8890/?
 token=b940b659aa0077da88a7b4247dc4fac2355ff6e405801078
 [I 14:50:55.231 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut 
 down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
 [C 14:50:55.234 NotebookApp] 

 Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
 to login with a token:
 http://localhost:8890/?
 token=b940b659aa0077da88a7b4247dc4fac2355ff6e405801078
```

Although a blank page opens up in my default browser (have chosen IE, out of the few installed) with webpage address:

```
http://localhost:8890/tree?token=b6a5317718c42147edea2aac32ebd401ea091c730d3daeeb
```

Also, am unable to run from command prompt the command 'python' as gives the error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Sorry, but despite my best efforts, my understanding is very poor of the installation process, and how path is to be included. Also, do not know if my installation being done in E: drive is causing these issues, i.e. not the C: drive. 
Please give examples, or verbose explanations, or similar sites' links.

---

Update 1: There is a separate 'Anaconda Command Prompt' for viewing the Anaconda Navigator's installed version of Python. It is accessible via the 'Start' menu. Found [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgjEUcccRwM) quite helpful.

Comment: To run scripts from Anaconda (such as jupyter and python) from the terminal, you must add the path to your user environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing nodejs:

try downloading and installing from:
https://nodejs.org/en/.

This should solve the problem with Jupyterlab.

I'm not a user of Anaconda Navigator, but, as far as I can see, it uses enviroments to manage python installations.
You should create at least one enviroment from Navigator and select it before trying to run python.

More info from Anaconda Navigator documentation here:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/getting-started